# Data input to php

Tags: php

I have data to the server via ajax in the following format:

```
$bd = $_GET['baseData'];
```

This gives:

```
$bd = ["privacy:0","father:{\"ID\":122}","mother:{\"ID\":0,\"born_name\":\"JONES\",\"first_names\":\"Mary\",\"YoB\":1812,\"YBq\":\"\",\"PoB\":\"\",\"DoB\":\"\",\"MoB\":\"\",\"living\":0,\"gender\":0,\"temp\":1}"];
```

If I use:

```
json_decode($_GET['baseData']);
```

it gives:

```
$bd = Array ( [0] => privacy:0 [1] => father:{"ID":122} [2] => mother:{"ID":0,"born_name":"JONES","first_names":"Mary","YoB":1812,"YBq":"","PoB":"","DoB":"","MoB":"","living":0,"gender":0,"temp":1} )
```

[

How do I extract this to an object so I can access the values using (for example):

```
$bd.mother
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive JSON to an array

```php
$data=json_decode($bd, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$bd = $_GET['baseData'];
$bd = preg_replace('#\[(.+?)\]#', '{$1}', $bd);
$bd = json_decode($bd);
$bd->mother...
```